# backpropagation: why find the global minimum instead of the value of zero

Tags: gradient-descent, error-propagation, backpropagation

in back propagation, you use gradient descent to find the stationary point on the equation of the Error = (in terms of weight).

But don't we want the error to be equal to zero? if the error is zero, then the weights have calculated the concept correctly

So why are we trying to calculate the stationary point of the error in terms of weight instead of just when the error equals zero? (or even better when the error equals zero and is a stationary point)

I understand that the error is changing with different weights, though why do we want the change of error to be zero instead of the actual error itself be zero?

Comment: What if the minimum error is greater than zero?

Comment: thanks ssdecontrol, after watching the tutorial several times again I realised I read the x axis wrong thanks anyway

Comment: 1) The real world is noisy.  If you worked with real world data and got zero error then you did something wrong.  2) Cross-validation is essential.  If you got zero once, check to make sure you get it 5 times in a row.  Keeping a holdout/validation set isn't a bad idea either - you could be overfitting.  3) There are "cliffs".  In any "production" system you want the setpoints far from the edge.  That means you should quantify what is going on around your setting to avoid things like [DeepFool](http://gitxiv.com/posts/iZpWrvKdXmtRaQusa/deepfool-a-simple-and-accurate-method-to-fool-deep-neural)